# react-native vs reactXP

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, reactxp

I have started developing an application for all the three platforms (web, ios and android) with single code base.

I came across these two libraries and I want to know which one is better and why?

Also, I came across a lot of open source react-native projects, For example [React Navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation),
[Lottie](https://github.com/react-community/lottie-react-native).

Can I integrate react-navigation (or any popular react-native module) in my react-native-web or reactXP application?

Please provide your inputs and TIA.

Comment: While I wouldn't be able to tell you which React framework is better, since you stated "I am new to mobile applications development" I would just throw a bit of advice out there: Instead of trying to tackle 3 different paradigms on your first go (web, iOS, Android) it may be beneficial to learn a couple using native languages to better understand lifecycle, memory management, threading, handling user interaction, etc. Since React is an abstraction on top of all that, debugging can get difficult if you don't understand the underlying components.

Answer (score 1):

[react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) is a framework for building iOS and Android applications using React. You can read more about the React Native bridge concept [here](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-react-native-bridge-concept-e9526066ddb8)

[ReactXP](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/docs/getting-started.html) - is a set of components/API which built on top of [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), [React](https://reactjs.org/), [React Native Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows) to simplify building cross-platform applications for multiple platforms *(iOs, Android, UWP, Web)* with one API for all of them. It is like jQuery which tries to solve the problem with cross-browser compatibility issues. The similar we can say about ReactXP - it tries to provide API/Components which works on several platforms.

> Can I integrate react-navigation (or any popular react-native module) in my react-native-web or reactXP application?

*ReactXP:* It is possible, however, it is not recommended. Usually, react-native plugins support only `iOS` and `Android` *(there are exceptions and some of them support `Windows`)*, so, you need to care about implementation for other platforms. [ReactXP](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/docs/getting-started.html) has several [extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/reactxp/tree/master/extensions), including [navigation](https://github.com/Microsoft/reactxp/tree/master/extensions/navigation).

Answer (score 1):

We use RXP as much as possible, and then create a different set of components for the web vs mobile.

For example on the web, you most likely want an `<a>` tag with a `href` prop to support opening links in new tabs. And on mobile you obviously don't. In this case we have implemented the `<Link>` component for each platform.

Same goes for navigation, modals, selects, etc.., and other platform specific things like localstorage implementation.